# Where is wintitle used?

Tags: xsl-fo, dita, dita-ot

I'm a DITA-OT newbie. I've recently installed version 3.1.2 and customized the  wintitle element in ui-domain-attr.xsl of my custom plugin folder as follows:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="wintitle">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-style">italic</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

When I render a pdf based on the document sequence.ditamap(which is part of the dita-ot folder), I see no change. What am I doing wrong.
PS: I have also updated custom.xsl(attr)

Comment: I made a similar modification what you had and it worked for me. Tested with Oxygen and modified file located at \org.dita.pdf2\cfg\fo\attrs\ui-domain-attr.xsl. 

Wintitle seems to be italic after the modifications. 

Maybe the problem is in the custom.xsl or you are calling DITA OT with wrong parameter or such?

Comment: Will check again. Maybe it works and I haven't seen it.                               Given a pdf such as http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf, which element there is the wintitle? Is it the text in the header?

Comment: Cannot say from PDF which is wintitle. I tested with this kind of topic: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id="concept_shw_kbc_kfb">
 <title>Test topic</title>
 <shortdesc><wintitle>This is wintitle</wintitle></shortdesc>
 <conbody>
  <p>Para</p>
  <p>Para with wintitle <wintitle>this is wintitle</wintitle></p>
 </conbody>
</concept>

Comment: Thanks for your help!